# How do I renforce a cardboard antenna for outside use?

Tags: outdoor, laminate, tv-antenna

I bought Mohu Releaf cardboard antenna. It works much better outside than inside. Mohu explicitly advises against outdoor use of its indoor models, yet I wrapped it in a plastic bag and hung it out of window.  It looks a bit shabby so I am looking for ways to improve both the look and protection against elements.

I tried placing antenna between window glasses yet it gets less channels than outside. I have a big outside antenna, again it gets less channels.

[image]

Dimensions: 9″ x 11.5″

Effect of elements on Leaf antennas
http://mohu.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/4000026474-can-i-use-my-leaf-curve-antenna-outside-or-in-an-attic-

Releaf model
https://releaf.gomohu.com/#specs

Update. I used it in a plastic bag to reduce deterioration yet eventually bought Winegard Elite on a sale, now have a few channels more. May be will use the leaf  with bedroom television.

Comment: Cardboard is not a material known for its weather resistance... Have you considered just getting one designed to be used outdoors?  It would likely be cheaper than properly weatherproofing your currently very weather susceptible one.

Comment: I have one but it is big, bulky and gets less channels. My plan B is to wait until this one deteriorates than if I still into tv switch back to big metal one or buy a new one. Also a friend promised to return me an antenna once pandemic is over. I hear outside antenna Winegard 7550 catches more channels  than cardboard Releaf, yet it costs nearly $200

Comment: Fair enough, though I feel like there must be options available somewhere between small, cheap, cardboard and large, expensive, metal -- a small, cheap, plastic one would probably work well for you.  You can either wait until your cardboard one wears out, or sell it while it's still working to someone who can use it indoors, and buy one rated for outdoor use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk that it might alter the properties of the cardboard in some way that might matter at radio-frequencies, I'd slather it in epoxy resin for waterproofing and follow up with a coat or two of spar varnish for UV protection.

Comment: Make sense yet not sure I would go for that considering the different epoxy resins have varying effects on radio waves. That it is one should use an appropriate epoxy

Comment: Potential metallic components or pigments are probably greater risk than epoxy itself https://www.reddit.com/r/rfelectronics/comments/a7wbkh/is_opaque_epoxy_transparent_to_rf_at_433_or_900mhz/

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree strongly with the suggestion to get an outdoor rated antenna, however, if you really want to attempt to use your cardboard antenna out in the weather, I'd suggest plastic lamination.

I'm not sure how big the antenna is, but they make lamination machines for 8.5 x 11" paper and they're cheap enough for home purchase. If you need something bigger, a local print shop may be able to do it for you or at least direct you to where it could be done in your town.

Comment: antenna is 9 x  11.5 yet it contains a metal cylinder that connects cable to the cardboard body. Would it jam the lamination machine?

Comment: the cable connection wouldn't make it through the laminator my wife has, but it might be possible with a professional/commercial machine. Frankly, [Ecnerwal's suggestion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/197827/34147) sounds better than lamination.

Comment: Thanks I check with local staples outlet or whatever available - your idea sounds simpler and I am not exactly handyman

Comment: you yon can  seal laminating pouches with a iron like used for pressing clothes, dealing with the "puck" where the cable connects would be tricky though. maybe do the epoxy thing there instead,  lay paper or foil over the pouch to keep the hot-melt laminating glue off the iron.